# Find downtimes and calculate lengths of downtime

Tags: mysql

My question very closely resembles the question here: [SQL - Find all down times and the lengths of the downtimes from MySQL data (set of rows with time stamps and status messages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658666/sql-find-all-down-times-and-the-lengths-of-the-downtimes-from-mysql-data-set/11659295#11659295)

I have my code all but working. I have a dataset that looks like this. I want to calculate the length of time with a '0' state.

```
+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| created_at          | fk_check_id | status |
+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| 2019-05-03 08:35:22 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 08:36:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:37:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:38:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:39:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 08:40:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 08:41:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:42:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:43:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:51:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:52:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:53:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:54:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 08:55:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 08:56:22 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 08:57:22 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 09:01:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 09:02:21 |          12 |      1 |
| 2019-05-03 09:03:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 09:04:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 09:05:22 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 09:06:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 09:07:21 |          12 |      0 |
| 2019-05-03 09:08:21 |          12 |      0 |
+---------------------+-------------+--------+
```

My SQL query looks like this:

```
  SELECT d.start_time
     , d.ended_time
  FROM (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i
             , @start := IF(s.status = '0' AND (@status = '1' OR @i = 1), s.created_at, @start) AS start_time
             , @ended := IF(s.status = '1' AND @status = '0', s.created_at, NULL) AS ended_time
             , @status := s.status
         FROM (SELECT t.created_at
                    , t.status
                 FROM logs t
                WHERE t.status IN ('1','0') AND fk_check_id=12
                ORDER BY t.created_at ASC, t.status ASC
              ) s
         JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @status := '1', @ended := NULL, @start := NULL) i
      ) d
WHERE d.start_time IS NOT NULL
  AND d.ended_time IS NOT NULL
```

And it returns results like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 2019-05-03 08:35:22
            [ended_time] => 2019-05-03 08:36:21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 2019-05-03 08:39:21
            [ended_time] => 2019-05-03 08:41:21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 2019-05-03 08:54:21
            [ended_time] => 2019-05-03 08:56:22
        )

)
```

Everything is working, except that it doesn't return the very last "down" block, because it hasn't been followed by a completed "up" entry yet. How can I return the most recent row and use that as my "ended_time" until a completed "up" block is entered?

I'm trying to calculate total downtime, and because that last entry isn't yet listed, my results are skewed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using? If you are using MySQL 8 you could probably swap your current ended select with something like this:

```
, @ended := IF((s.status = '1' OR (s.created_at = MAX(s.created_at) OVER())) AND @status = '0', s.created_at, NULL) AS ended_time
```

If you are not using MySQL 8 this will not help you. MySQL 8 introduced the OVER() function.

Comment: I didn't even know MySQL had come out with a new version. I'm running 5.7.26 currently, but if this fixes the problems, I may just upgrade.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. Really appreciate the help. Took me a sec to get MySQL upgraded to version 8, but it needed to be done anyway to win-win.